# Preventing atomatic driver loading on live boot disk

Tags: linux, boot, drivers, grub, video

I'm preparing ubuntu-base live boot disk.
It works fine mostly,  but on some machines equped with Nvidia Quadro cards
the default **nouveau** driver causes problems (temporary freezes).
I've determined that buy blacklisting **nouveau** driver (in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf) I can fix the problem.
However this approach inhibits **nouveau** driver for every nvidia equipped machine which
is an overkill.
Of course, i can detect the presence of the Quadro card after the boot, blacklist it, do
**update-initramfs -u** and reboot but this approach modifies  live boot disk and I would like to avoid that.
I wonder if there is a way to detect the presence of nvidia Quadro somewhere very early in the boot sequence and prevent loading of the offending driver and fall back to standard VESA driver.

Comment: You could patch the kernel driver so that it ignored your PCI IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the problem as following:
I've blacklisted the **nouveau** driver and installed
a service which upon execution checks for presence of offending video card
and does nothing if the card is present.
if another NVIDIA card is found the service does **modprobe nouveau**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).